# Is every free monoid a pure monoid and vice versa?

Tags: monoid

A pure monoid is a monoid where only the identity has an inverse. Is every free monoid pure, and conversely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, free monoids are pure. By definition a free monoid on a set is the monoid of words consisting of elements from that set, and there is no cancellation, so no inverses, apart from the empty word.

The non-negative rationals under addition is not a free monoid, but it is pure.

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal example**. The multiplicative monoid $\{1,0\}$ is pure, but not free.